# sqlite3 INSERT INTO query in python, string format

Tags: python, sqlite

python 3.7, vscode

This works:

```
def insert_song(cursor):
    header = get_header(cursor)
    query = "INSERT INTO `songs` ('song', 'album', 'artist', 'genre', 'duration', 'price') VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?);"
    cursor.execute(query, get_info(cursor))
    connection.commit()
```

This:

```
def insert_song(cursor):
    header = get_header(cursor)
    query = "INSERT INTO `songs` ({}) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?);".format(header)
    cursor.execute(query, get_info(cursor))
    connection.commit()
```

generates following error:

```
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "(": syntax error
```

---

the return of the "get_header(cursor)" function is following tuple:

```
('song', 'album', 'artist', 'genre', 'duration', 'price')
```

---

as i get hinted, it's a problem with .format which i have to define something additional but i didn't find it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you pass tuple, you get also the brackets, so you will have double brackets in your query

Try

```
query = "INSERT INTO `songs` {} VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?);".format(header)
```

or even better using f-string

```
query = f"INSERT INTO `songs` {header} VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?);"
```

or directly

```
query = f"INSERT INTO `songs` {get_header()} VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?);"
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the format of the problem comes from the format string . It will have double () because formatting of header will include header () :

```
header=('a','b')
query="-({})-".format(header)
print(query)
```

This will print :

```
-(('a', 'b'))-
```

If you suppress the () from the format, you gay what you want :

```
query2="-{}-".format(header)
print(query2)
```

Prints out :

```
-('a', 'b')-
```

Answer (score 0):

as buran in the comment stated:

`` query = "INSERT INTO songs` {} VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?);".format(header) ``

works